# I want to convert exist clause into In clause of the following query

Tags: sql, subquery, exists, correlated-subquery, in-clause

```
SELECT SupplierName
FROM Suppliers
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ProductName FROM Products 
              WHERE Products.SupplierID = Suppliers.supplierID AND Price < 20);
```

I want to convert the existing clause into an `IN` clause of the query.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want that? Functionality would be the same, and in general an `EXISTS` tends to perform better than an `IN`. Also, what did you try yourself, and why didn't it work as expected?

Comment: I am trying one query where exists is not performing better compare to IN, inner query(subquery) is correlated subquery and has less records than outer query. Please suggest me which will be better to IN use  or EXISTS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
SELECT SupplierName
FROM Suppliers
WHERE Suppliers.SupplierID IN (
    SELECT Products.SupplierID
    FROM Products 
    WHERE Price < 20
)
```